# My container is being exiting itself while creating , What is the solution to solve this issue?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, docker-container, docker-image

Am trying to build a docker image for my django webapp and upload it to the docker hub . Then pull that image using kubernetes . Am in trouble creating container out of my docker image , Whenever I create my container is exiting itself, Am I doing any mistake while creating a Dockerfile ?

DOCKER FILE :

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /django-app

COPY requirments.txt /django-app/

RUN pip install -r requirments.txt

ADD . /django-app

COPY . /django-app/

CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

[image: FILES]

REQUIRMENTS FILE(requirments.txt)

```
Django>=4.0
psycopg2>=2.8
```

Container exiting:

[image]

While I checked my container logs , It shows "python: can't open file '/django-app/./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

[image]

Comment: Why are you using both `ADD` and `COPY` to copy the same folder? Furthermore it seems python cannot find the `manage.py` script thus it immediately exits and thus also the container shuts down. Verify, that the file really exists in the correct location. Ie try setting the startup command to a simple shell, run the container and check if the file is really where you expect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing

```
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Python will look for a file called `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` which doesn't exist. You need to split the parameters up so it becomes

```
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

You can also use the simpler syntax of

```
CMD python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the path when starting

```
CMD [ "python", "/django-app/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```